# Ajax call for update takes me on top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sammy.js

I am using sammy javascript framework. Problem is when I click over below anchor browser take me on top of page .... How can I prevent this....

Here is html anchor

```
<a href="#/duplicate/Chart1">Duplicate</a>
```

and here is JS sammy listner

```
this.get('#/duplicate/:id', function(context) {
    chartName=this.params['id'];

  for(i=0;i<chartJSONS.length;i++){
    if(chartJSONS[i].chart.renderTo==chartName){
        var obj = jQuery.extend(true, {}, chartJSONS[i]);
        var dupChart=obj.chart.renderTo+"_duplicate";
        obj.chart.renderTo=dupChart;
        chartJSONS[chartJSONS.length++]=obj; 
    }
  }
  $('#chart').html('');
  createCharts();

    return false;
  });
```

Any help is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');

});
```

I suggest you to add a class to every a element you want to handle like this:

```
<a href="#/duplicate/Chart1" class="myclass">Duplicate</a>

$('.myclass').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but in your example you are not using ajax... But in my case when I get ajax response then this all happens... I also tried with class as you said but it also not working... May be there is something to do with sammy's get method that sends ajax request.....

Comment: what exactly isn't working? have you tried defining `obj = $(this);` outside the ajax request and using `window.location.hash = obj.attr('href');`?

Comment: Sorry Fabian ... Actually problem was with my code.... Actually
 code "$('#chart').html('');" was making height of div to 0 due to which scroll bars gets disappeared and the re populate which take me on top of page.... All the process was so fast that I never think about the height.... now I got it fixed... Thanks for your kind response and help...

Comment: Good to hear that you could figure that out. Things like that happen to all of us. Thanks for accepting anyway:)

Answer (score 1):

you need to cancel the navigation after the click event.

because the # navigates your browser to top of the page.

something like:

```
$('.allDuplicates').click(function(){
return false;
});
```

or use something else than

```
<a>
```

use for example div and you're ok.